# How to use the Drools knowledge agent for rule data change detection

Tags: drools

I plan to use Drools as the rule engine for our business case. I am planning to use Drools template to define the rules and Java Objects as the data source. The Java objects are populated from Mongo DB collection at startup. If some data changes in the Mongo DB collection during the day, I want drools to automatically take the new data into consideration while applying the rules. I believe there is something called as knowledge agent which can be done to do that but I am not sure how exactly that can be done. Any help appreciated. I plan to use the latest drools version (8.44.0.final) but I am ok to use older version if this is not supported in the latest version.

Comment: Are you trying to use the mongo data to generate the rules or as the inputs when firing the rules?